# Anjuta crashes when open *.ui file

Tags: 14.04, ide, glade, anjuta

I'm using Anjuta IDE version 3.12.0, Ubuntu 14.10 64bit.
Whenever I open a *.ui file, Anjuta crashes:

- if I double click at the *ui file, or right click and choose **Open** or **Open with Glade interface designer**, the IDE crashes.
- if I right click at the *.ui file and choose **Open with Glade** it open normally.

Thanks in advanced.

Comment: On the anjuta mailing list I saw a mention that this happens when you use a glade that is not compiled for the anjuta you are using. You need to report a bug on this (see http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug ). From command line `ubuntu-bug anjuta` will gather the information about versions etc developers need to know.

Answer (score 0):

It is a bug in the program, so read Rinzwinds answer.
There is a work around:
install Glade and open the .ui file in that program.
hope it helps a bit until the bug is fixed.